# QGIS 3 Python support disabled Linux

Tags: python, qgis-3

Couldn't find a similar question for Linux, just Windows.

I'm running Linux Mint 19.3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 70, in 
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 24, in 
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.14' not found (required by /home/jrickards/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so)


Python version:
3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0]

QGIS version:
3.10.5-A Coruña 'A Coruña', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/jrickards/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python', '/home/jrickards/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/jrickards/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144003/ubuntu-18-04-couldnt-load-sip-module-qgis

Just remove PyQt5 using pip3:

```
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
```

And install form apt:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Works just fine.

Comment: This answer is useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Is pyqt5 installed ? You can write this in a terminal to do so :

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5 pyqt5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools
```

Comment: ran this, no difference

Answer (score 0):

If the other answer's suggestion to remove the module installed with pip does not work, telling you that the module doesn't exist:

```bsh
pip3 uninstall PyQt5
WARNING: Skipping PyQt5 as it is not installed.
```

... It might be that the module was installed for a different version of Python to the default one for the user. This might happen if pip was used with `sudo` (therefore installing a module for root's default version of python).

In that case, you might have to try to uninstall with sudo too:

```bsh
sudo pip3 uninstall PyQt5
```

You can investigate the version mismatch with:

```py
python3 --version
sudo python3 --version
```

...and check which one matches your error message.